# WebLogic return Bad Request for a empty host header request

Tags: http, post, weblogic

I'm trying to call a WebService hosted into a WebLogic server. Everytime I call it with a empty value into the "host" header, I receive a "400 - Bad Request" response. If I put something into the host header, the request is ok and I can consume the WS. 
The RFC says:

> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request 
>   messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host 
>   name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST 
>   be given with an empty value

When I send the host with empty value, I'm sending the URI without the host name, so, by the RFC, I'm doing ok.

This is my HTTP header that's receiving a Bad Request:

```
POST /myContent/myWebService HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: mySOAPcall
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: 
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 709
```

If I put the host, it works fine:

```
POST http://mydomain.com.br/myContent/myWebService HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: mySOAPcall
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: mydomain.com.br
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 709
```

Am I missing something into the request with the empty host header?

Comment: what happens when you don't send any `Host` header?

Comment: I receive a 400 - Bad Request too, which is correct accordingly the RFC: "A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages....All Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header field."

Comment: request without host header should be handled by default virtual host if it is defined on your server. Host header is used to to distinguish among resources while servicing requests for multiple host names on a single IP address. From RFC 7230 (5.5): Recipients of an HTTP/1.0 request that lacks a Host header field might need to use heuristics (e.g., examination of the URI path for something unique to a particular host) in order to guess the effective request URI's authority component.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the the RFC specifications, I couldn't find the following quote:

> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be given with an empty value

However in section 3.2 I found out that:

> Invalid whitespace around field-names is now required to be rejected,
> because accepting it represents a security vulnerability.  The ABNF
> productions defining header fields now only list the field value.
> (Section 3.2)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2

Could it be possible that the empty value is interpreted as invalid whitespace?

Comment: You can see the first quote in section 14.23 - Host, of the following link:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Regarding the second quote, it says that you cannot have a whitespace around field-names. It's not related to the field-value.

Comment: Thanks for linking it, I was having difficulty searching that document! 

Looking further into that passage it says that the `All Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header field.` 

Perhaps if the lack they are describing is when the field-value is empty?

Comment: Nahhh, not really I think. Because it would be weird to say in one part that the "host header must be given with an empty value", and in another part say that it cannot be empty. 

The lack is related to the presence of the header field only.